# Display picture in gallery

Tags: ios, image-gallery

I looked trough google and SO but did not find an answer to my question. I found a lot of topics about the Picker but I want to display an Image and not select one.

I have a Storyboard with various data, one of them being an ImageView with a scaled Image I receive from my database with Parse.

Now I want to display the full image when it is pressed. I know I could create a new View for this, but I was wondering if it would be possible to open this with Apple's Gallery or if there is alternative solution with Cocoapod that would simplify the displaying of the image.

I don't want to build a GUI just to view the full image and being able to zoom/share etc. if there is an already existing solution.

Comment: Great to down/close vote the question... I found no topic about any way to display an image (Even one which exists in the album) in the gallery anywhere yet

Comment: try this https://github.com/NYTimes/NYTPhotoViewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into `UIImagePickerController` should only take a short time to implement and easy to get the image the user picks but you cannot change the appearance or extend the functionality.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/

EDIT: Due to my misunderstanding.

This GitHub has a very good and easy solution for simply displaying an image in a full screen manner with built in gesture control.

https://github.com/bufferapp/buffer-ios-image-viewer

One of the best parts is that you can initialise it with URL/ALAsset/PHAsset/UIImage all through the same initialiser.

```
BFRImageViewController *imageVC = [[BFRImageViewController alloc] initWithImageSource:@[image]];
```

Comment: not a relevant answer

Comment: I don't want to PICK the image, but DISPLAY it, I already have the image

Comment: It seems as it is not possible to open the gallery with a specific picture so I will try to use your EDITED solution with BFR